# How to add UITableViewCell on UIView TableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have `UIView` Class which added `UITableView` 
Now i created `UITableViewCell` wants to added custom cell on `UITableViewCell`.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder{

    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
            //do somthing
        filterColorTableView.delegate = self;
        filterColorTableView.dataSource = self;

        [self.filterColorTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FilterColor" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"COLORCELL"];

        colorNameList = [[ColorModelClass colorListNames]allKeys];
        filterColorTableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    }

    return self;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    static NSString *tableViewCellIdentifier = @"COLORCELL";
    FilterColorTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableViewCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.lbl_ColorName setText:@"Welcome"] ;
    cell.lbl_ColorName.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [cell.colorImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle.png"]];
    return cell;

}

Crash Report Message:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier COLORCELL - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

Which is creating cell object but the associated lbl_ColorName and colorImage is nil alway's

Note: I do not used UIViewController only UIView class is used in this approach.

On UIView Xib added UITableView and taken another custom UITableViewCell with in the same file's Owner.

[image]

Comment: have you registered the cell with the tableview? in order to dequeue it?

Comment: @HarmVanRisk Yes i did.

Comment: Have you added the identifier to the Attributes inspector when highlighting the cell in the xib file?

Comment: @HarmVanRisk check the attachment.

Answer (score 0):

First [register the custom cell class](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614888-registerclass?language=objc) anytime at or after viewDidLoad.  Having done that, [the dequeue method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614878-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifie) that was introduced along with class or nib registration is `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`.  Note the new indexPath parameter.

It always returns an initialized cell, so the nil check is superfluous...

```
FilterColorTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:filterTableViewCell forIndexPath:indexPath];
// deleted if(cell == nil){...}
```

Comment: I try to register and and updated its now crashing 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier COLORCELL - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'  in identifier i added "COLORCELL",  I updated the question for more in detail.

Comment: Hmm.  I didn't realize this was in the context of initWithCoder.  This sounds like the work is being done in init is too early.  Can you move the table setup  stuff to `didLayoutSubviews`